# Properly identifying memory leak with GC and LOH

Tags: c#-4.0, memory-management, garbage-collection

This may have been asked a few different ways, but this is a relatively new field to me so forgive me if it is redundant and point me on my way.

Essentially I have created a data collection engine that take high speed data (up to thousands of points a second) and stores them in a database.

The database is dynamic, so the statements being fed to the database are dynamically created in code as well, this in turn required a great deal of string manipulation. All of the strings however are declared within scope of asynchronous event handler methods, so they should fall out of scope as soon as the method completes.

As this application runs, its memory usage according to task manager / process explorer, slowly but steadily increases, so it would seem that something was not getting properly disposed and or collected.

If I attach CDB -p  (yes I am loading the sos.dll from the CLR) and do a !dumpheap I see that the majority of this is being used by System.String, as well if I !dumpheap -type System.String, and the !do the addresses I see the exact strings (the SQL statements).

however if I do a !gcroot on the any of the addresses, I get "Found 0 unique roots (run '!GCRoot -all' to see all roots)." that in turn if I try as it suggests I get "Invalid argument -all" O.o

So after some googling, and some arguments concerning that unrooted objects will eventually be collected by GC, that this is not an issue.. I looked to see, and it appears 84% of my problem is sitting on the LOH (where depending on which thread you look at where, may or may not get processed for GC *unless* there is a memory constraint on the machine or I explicitly tell it to collect which is considered bad according to everything I can find)

So what I need to know is, is this essentially true, that this is not a memory leak, it is simply the system leaving stuff there until it HAS to be reclaimed, and if so how then do I tell that I do or do not have a legitimate memory leak.

This is my first time working the debugger external to the application as I have never had to address this sort of issue before, so I am very new to that portion, this is a learning experience.

Application is written in VS2012 Pro, C#, it is multi-threaded, and a console application is wrapping the API for testing, but will eventually be a Windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you read is true, managed applications use a memory model where objects pile on until you reach a certain memory threshold (calculated based on the amount of physical memory on your system and your application's real growth rate), after which all(*) "dead" objects get squished by the rest of the useful memory, making it one contiguous block for allocation speed.

So yes, don't worry about your memory steadily increasing until you're several tens of MB up and no collection has taken place.

(*) - is actually more complicated by multiple memory pools (based on object size and lifetime length), such that the system isn't constantly probing very long lived objects, and by finalizers. When an object has a finalizer, instead of being freed, the memory gets squished over them but they get moved to a special queue, the finalizer queue, where they wait for the finalizer to run on the UI thread (keep in mind the GC runs on a separate thread), and only then it finally gets freed.

Comment: Just as a note however, all of this is not to say leaks are impossible. In fact currying adds a lot of ways you can leak handles if you're not careful.

Comment: Is there than any way to fact check this is indeed the case. There are very little memory restrictions on my development machine (32GB of ram, I do a lot of concurrent VMs for testing)  The end environment will be machines where this could in theory run for long periods, and I do not want people to come back to get data to find an out of memory exception a month ago shut it down.. Id est, how do you *really* track a memory leak then? (or what is the accepted good enough standard)

Comment: Look at your objects and how they're used, look at your curried functions and your event handlers, it's not hard to avoid leaks in a managed language like C#. If you want to see it visually, I recommend dotMemory by JetBrains, I think they have a trial version to play with.

Comment: To put this into perspective, for the first hour of run, I was looking at a footprint of about 15m, by the end of two days it had grown to 75m, the end machines may be at 2gb running w7, they are small industrial machines, at that rate I could in theory fill them in a couple of weeks or less if I am wrong on this.

Comment: Yeah at that rate you'll grow old and die before you see a GC. If you're really curious put a button that does `GC.Collect()` and you'll see the "zero point" at that point in time. If you click it at 5min intervals you should see similar values. Don't use that in production code though, it's just to get an idea of what's going on without intrusive tools (dotMemory)